# Uncaught error in ReactJS (default app)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an error message shown below. I would appreciate any comments to solve this issue. I only installed the default react app and ran in it Chrome.

I installed the default create react app using -

> create-react-app

When I open App.js in chrome I get the following message from the line -

> import React, { Component } from 'react'

The message is -

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

I have Mac as the OS.

I have the following package.json

```
{
  "name": "sat1",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.3.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h1 className="App-title">Blockchain</h1>
        </header>
        <p className="App-intro">
          To get started, edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;



// WEBPACK FOOTER //
// src/App.js
```

Comment: post your app.js to get proper reference.

Comment: What do you mean by "open App.js in chrome"?

Comment: use npm run build before start an application in your project root folder

Comment: @helb right . What you mean by open App.js in chrome ?

Comment: I mean the message is in the console in Chrome.

Comment: @TrevorOakley Sure, but how do you open the app? See create-react-apps' [Readme](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app#quick-overview) – you start the app by running `npm start` (in the app directory) and pointing your browser to [localhost:3000](http://localhost:3000/) (npm start opens it automatically if i recall correctly).

Comment: @helb yes that is how I have run it. The issue is related to the interpretation of the first line of the default code in Chrome.

Comment: That's weird. Chrome shouldn't see the code you posted, it gets "compiled" by babel.

Comment: can you share the webpack and babel configs

Comment: @TrevorOakley Just to be sure – is this what you did/do: https://vgy.me/kMk0f1.mp4 ? There's no reason why Chrome would complain about syntax errors…

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to use es6 syntax. whereas most of the browser don't have support yet. so you need a complier like babel which compiles and converts your code to es2015 version.

Comment: He's using `create-react-app` which has babel & webpack included.

Comment: I guess then he tried opening directly the app.js file in chrome

Comment: yeah, that's what i suspected, and asked in the comments, but he claims he runs it using npm start…